# Writing to a file in the current directory in java

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Solution{
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{
        int max=10;
        URL path = Solution.class.getResource("output.txt");
        File output = new File(path.getFile());
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(output));
        writer.write(Integer.toString(max));
        writer.close();

    }
}
```

I was trying to write data to an output.txt file which is current directory.The program has no erros but max value is not getting written on the output.txt file. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I ran the code and it writes value of `max` variable in `output.txt` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access the current directory you should reference the file directly, and use try with resources to clean up the output stream:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    int max=10;
    File output = new File("output.txt");
    System.out.println("Writing to: "+output.getAbsolutePath());
    try(BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(output))) {
        writer.write(Integer.toString(max));
    }
}
```

The code is simpler in later JDKs using `Path` and `Files`:

```
public static void main(String ... args) throws IOException {
    int max = 10;
    Path output = Path.of("output.txt"); // Use Paths.get in JDK9
    System.out.println("Writing to: "+output.toAbsolutePath());
    Files.writeString(output, Integer.toString(max));
}
```

Comment: But sir, after writing to the file output.txt i dont see any thing written to the file. I just see an empty file

Comment: You could add check the file contents after the try block, with: `System.out.println("Contents of: "+output.getAbsolutePath());         System.out.println(Files.readString(output.toPath()));`

Answer (score 1):

create a new folder and keep your java and output.txt file inside the folder then compile and run the program.
Hope it will solve your problem